# OSX partition failed

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I stumbled upon errors when I tried to partition my HD for an ubuntu partition. First it kept saying `Partition Failed: Filesystem Verification failed` That problem did disappear after a while. Probably when I repaired permissions. Then it kept saying `Could not unmount disk "HD"`

I tried unmounting disk manually, though that brought up `Filesystem verification failed` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to your problem:

`Filesystem verification` can be stopped by booting to single-user mode, and then typing in order:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
reboot
```

`Could not unmount disk` is because you are probably using it. Try booting from Recovery HD. If problem persists, boot Recovery from USB or use Internet Recovery to partition disk.